# get cookie value using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using jquery for getting the cookie value.

I have written this:

```
alert("hi");
alert($.cookie('product_code',{ path:'/'}));
```

but I am getting following error:

> jQuery is not defined. $ is not defined

Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` object does not exist. Include it first (via the `script` element pointing to its definition) and `$.cookie()`'s definition before you run this code.

Comment: <script src="/v/vspfiles/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

I have added this but still i am getting the error

Comment: @user985225 Read the answer again carefully.